# Connecting own OSRM server on leaflet routing machine?

Tags: leaflet, ubuntu, open-source-routing-machine

I have my OSRM running on UBUNTU.

How do I change the demo server of routing machine to my own OSRM server on Leaflet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to configure the settings as mentioned [here](http://www.liedman.net/leaflet-routing-machine/api/#l-routing-osrmv1). so it would be like this

```
L.Routing.control({
    waypoints: [
        L.latLng(57.74, 11.94),
        L.latLng(57.6792, 11.949)
    ],
    router: new L.Routing.OSRMv1({
        serviceUrl: url_to_your_service
    })
}).addTo(map);
```

Comment: I need the URL to pass a check to see my  geojson road on my browser because I get "404 not found: /viaroute?loc=45.18452,5.72094&amp;loc=45.36348,5.58775"

Comment: the url was "http://127.0.0.1:5000/route/v1/driving/13.388860,52.517037;13.385983,52.496891?steps=true" from point A 13.388860,52.517037 to point B 13.385983,52.496891

Comment: It worked for the url of my OSM service  url_to_your_service='MyLINUX IP :5000/route/v1'